# In Power BI dax, please help me out to count the total occurrences on consecutive number in "n" times

Tags: powerbi

I would like to count in Power BI the total counts when a value comes out in 3 consecutive order. Highly appreciated the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may denote your columns as "tme" and "val" and the table as "tbl": a two-step approach with a calculated column would look as follows:

**First**, we evaluate the time-difference as a **calculated column** in every row to the next-largest zero with time before the time of the respective row (see "EARLIER"). We further take the modulus with respect to 3, so that we expose all entries, which are 3, 6, 9 elements greater than the next-smaller zero.

```
__DiffToLargestZeroBeforeMod3 = MOD(tbl[tme] - CALCULATE(
    MAX(tbl[tme]),
    FILTER(tbl, tbl[val] = 0),
    tbl[tme] < EARLIER(tbl[tme])
), 3)
```

**Next**, we define a **measure**, which counts all '1' entries that have 3-modulo 0

```
_CntTriplets = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(tbl[val]),
    tbl[__DiffToLargestZeroBeforeMod3] = 0,
    tbl[val] = 1
)
```

Hope this does the job for you! Note, that this also works if the column were to start with three 1's, as the result from the MAX operator would be None and, e.g. 3-None = 3 for DAX. Also note, that the calculated column is probably not the most compute-efficient approach ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments.
But turns out an error in 2nd filter: tbl[tme] < EARLIER(tbl[tme])

Comment: Are you sure, you're defining a calculated column, not a measure?

Comment: I've editted the answer and set the calculated column and measure part in bold

Comment: appreciated the support. thank you very much.

Comment: Anytime! If the answer works, can you please mark as answered? Cheers!